# jquery tab like effect - show hide div on click

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery, and I'm trying to create a tab like effect "upon click, only a single div should show at a time", I have wrote the following, but I don't feel its the correct way of doing things even tho the my code works. 
Any idea how I can improve this? maybe make it a function?

here is a working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/amlife/opdzhzzz/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tabone").click(function(){
        $('#box-one').css("display", "block");
        $('#box-two').css("display", "none");
        $('#box-three').css("display", "none");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tabtwo").click(function(){
        $('#box-one').css("display", "none");
        $('#box-two').css("display", "block");
        $('#box-three').css("display", "none");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tabthree").click(function(){
        $('#box-one').css("display", "none");
        $('#box-two').css("display", "none");
        $('#box-three').css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use common class like `.box` based on that You can hide and show the div using selected     **[index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)**

### HTML

```
<ul id="ul-menu-list">
    <li id="tabone">How it Works</li>
    <li id="tabtwo">Features</li>
    <li id="tabthree">FAQ</li>
</ul>
<di id="box-one" class="box">Tab one</di>
<di id="box-two" class="box">Tab two</di>
<di id="box-three" class="box">Tab three</di>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ul-menu-list li").click(function () {
        $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();  // hide all divs and show the current div
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/opdzhzzz/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Only one click event and uses the newer `on` method.

```
$("#ul-menu-list").on('click','li', function(e) {
  $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `di` element is but this will work anyway for you, if structure is going to be same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul li").click(function(){
      $('di[id^="box-"]').css("display", "none");
      $('di[id^="box-"]').eq($(this).index()).css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/opdzhzzz/4/)